# Разница проектов в Delphi XE и Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi

В Delphi XE2 при создании простой формы с кнопкой Открыть, проект отлично работает в Windows PE (версия 3.0), а при создании такой же формы в Delphi XE - OpenDialog не срабатывает. В чём разница?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Delphi установлены с исходниками, сравните коды Execute в разных версиях.
Для XE2 он, разьросанный по модулям, такой:

```
function TOpenDialog.Execute(ParentWnd: HWND): Boolean;
begin
  Result := DoExecute(@GetOpenFileName, ParentWnd);
end;
```

---

```
function GetOpenFileName;      external commdlg32  name 'GetOpenFileNameW';
function GetOpenFileNameA;      external commdlg32  name 'GetOpenFileNameA';
function GetOpenFileNameW;      external commdlg32  name 'GetOpenFileNameW';
```

---

```
function TOpenDialog.DoExecute(Func: Pointer; ParentWnd: HWND): Bool;
const
  MultiSelectBufferSize = High(Word) - 16;
  OpenOptions: array [TOpenOption] of DWORD = (
    OFN_READONLY, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, OFN_HIDEREADONLY,
    OFN_NOCHANGEDIR, OFN_SHOWHELP, OFN_NOVALIDATE, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT,
    OFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT, OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST,
    OFN_CREATEPROMPT, OFN_SHAREAWARE, OFN_NOREADONLYRETURN,
    OFN_NOTESTFILECREATE, OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON, OFN_NOLONGNAMES,
    OFN_EXPLORER, OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS, OFN_ENABLEINCLUDENOTIFY,
    OFN_ENABLESIZING, OFN_DONTADDTORECENT, OFN_FORCESHOWHIDDEN);

  OpenOptionsEx: array [TOpenOptionEx] of DWORD = (OFN_EX_NOPLACESBAR);
var
  Option: TOpenOption;
  OptionEx: TOpenOptionEx;
  OpenFilename: TOpenFilename;

  function AllocFilterStr(const S: string): string;
  var
    P: PChar;
  begin
    Result := '';
    if S <> '' then
    begin
      Result := S + #0;  // double null terminators
      P := AnsiStrScan(PChar(Result), '|');
      while P <> nil do
      begin
        P^ := #0;
        Inc(P);
        P := AnsiStrScan(P, '|');
      end;
    end;
  end;

var
  FileDialogWrapper: TFileDialogWrapper;
  TempFilter, TempFilename, TempExt: string;
begin
  if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) and UseLatestCommonDialogs and
     StyleServices.Enabled and (Template = nil) and
     not (Assigned(FOnIncludeItem) or Assigned(FOnClose) or Assigned(FOnShow)) then
  begin
    // This requires Windows Vista or later
    if Func = @GetOpenFileName then
      FileDialogWrapper := TFileOpenDialogWrapper.Create(Self)
    else
      FileDialogWrapper := TFileSaveDialogWrapper.Create(Self);

    try
      Result := FileDialogWrapper.Execute(ParentWnd);
    finally
      FileDialogWrapper.Free;
    end;
    Exit;
  end;

  FFiles.Clear;
  FillChar(OpenFileName, SizeOf(OpenFileName), 0);
  with OpenFilename do
  begin
    if (Win32MajorVersion >= 5) and (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) or { Win2k }
    ((Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS) and (Win32MajorVersion >= 4) and (Win32MinorVersion >= 90)) then { WinME }
      lStructSize := SizeOf(TOpenFilename)
    else
      lStructSize := SizeOf(TOpenFilename) - (SizeOf(DWORD) shl 1) - SizeOf(Pointer); { subtract size of added fields }

    hInstance := SysInit.HInstance;
    TempFilter := AllocFilterStr(FFilter);
    lpstrFilter := PChar(TempFilter);
    nFilterIndex := FFilterIndex;
    FCurrentFilterIndex := FFilterIndex;
    if ofAllowMultiSelect in FOptions then
      nMaxFile := MultiSelectBufferSize else
      nMaxFile := MAX_PATH;
    SetLength(TempFilename, nMaxFile + 2);
    lpstrFile := PChar(TempFilename);
    FillChar(lpstrFile^, (nMaxFile + 2) * SizeOf(Char), 0);
    StrLCopy(lpstrFile, PChar(FFileName), nMaxFile);
    if (FInitialDir = '') and ForceCurrentDirectory then
      lpstrInitialDir := '.'
    else
      lpstrInitialDir := PChar(FInitialDir);
    lpstrTitle := PChar(FTitle);
    Flags := OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
    FlagsEx := 0;

    for Option := Low(Option) to High(Option) do
      if Option in FOptions then
        Flags := Flags or OpenOptions[Option];
    if NewStyleControls then
    begin
      Flags := Flags xor OFN_EXPLORER;
      if (Win32MajorVersion >= 5) and (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) or { Win2k }
      ((Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS) and (Win32MajorVersion >= 4) and (Win32MinorVersion >= 90)) then { WinME }
        for OptionEx := Low(OptionEx) to High(OptionEx) do
          if OptionEx in FOptionsEx then
            FlagsEx := FlagsEx or OpenOptionsEx[OptionEx];
    end
    else
      Flags := Flags and not OFN_EXPLORER;
    TempExt := FDefaultExt;
    if (TempExt = '') and (Flags and OFN_EXPLORER = 0) then
    begin
      TempExt := ExtractFileExt(FFilename);
      Delete(TempExt, 1, 1);
    end;
    if TempExt <> '' then lpstrDefExt := PChar(TempExt);
    if (ofOldStyleDialog in Options) or not NewStyleControls then
      lpfnHook := DialogHook
    else
      lpfnHook := ExplorerHook;

    if Template <> nil then
    begin
      Flags := Flags or OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE;
      lpTemplateName := Template;
      if FTemplateModule <> 0 then
        hInstance := FTemplateModule;
    end;
    if Application.ModalPopupMode <> pmNone then
    begin
      FRedirector := TRedirectorWindow.Create(nil);
      with TRedirectorWindow(FRedirector) do
      begin
        FCommonDialog := Self;
        FFormHandle := ParentWnd;
      end;
      hWndOwner := FRedirector.Handle;
    end
    else
      hWndOwner := ApplicationMainHandle;
    Result := TaskModalDialog(Func, OpenFileName);
    if Result then
    begin
      GetFileNames(OpenFilename);
      if (Flags and OFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT) <> 0 then
        Include(FOptions, ofExtensionDifferent) else
        Exclude(FOptions, ofExtensionDifferent);
      if (Flags and OFN_READONLY) <> 0 then
        Include(FOptions, ofReadOnly) else
        Exclude(FOptions, ofReadOnly);
      FFilterIndex := nFilterIndex;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Написан вопрос достаточно непонятно :)
Насколько я понял, вы хотите создавать в **DelphiXE** приложения под ОС, отличную от **Windows** для PC , в частности, под **WindowsPE**.  Но это невозможно: поддержка платформ, отличных от **Windows**,  появилась только в **DelphiXE2** и только при использовании **FireMonkey**

Comment: Понимаете в чём дело, на Delphi 7 тоже нормально работает !

Comment: Не работает на версиях 2007-2010 и XE, а на XE2 работает...

Comment: Ничего не понимаю, опишите ситуацию конкретно желательно с кодом.

Comment: Да описывать нечего, создаю голую форму с кнопкой, на кнопке код:
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute
    then ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar (OpenDialog1.FileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
end;

Comment: Тестировал на разных Delphi, работает только на 7-ке и XE2.
EXE-шник собирается, программа работает, но в WindowsPE просто не появляется диалог выбора файла...

Comment: Не пишите по 2 коментария, количество коентариев в одном вопросе ограничено 10.
Так теперь по вопросу, у Вас не компелится код или готовый екзешник не запускает выбраную программу?

Comment: @SoftR, WindowsPE это просто live-cd версия обычной винды.